# Adding instrumentation (aka injecting into scripts) using chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, instrumentation, javascript-injection

My goal is to inject instrumentation code into certain scripts of certain websites to then lately collect the data using chrome extension and upload it to a centralized DB.

The last time I tried this was around 2016 when I achieved this using "onbeforescriptexecute" in a user script I added to firefox using GreaseMonkey, back then chrome didn't support this at all. Now I've looked around here and the newest I found was around the same yeah mentioning "onbeforescriptexecute" is not supported in chrome and offering a workaround with a link to a GitHub page that no longer exists.

So are there any modern ways to intercept scripts loading into a web page in chrome extension content script? What I need is to catch each script before it loads, parse, inject instrumentation and then proceed to run it.

Comment: UserScripts are your best bet if you're wanting to manipulate live. TamperMonkey is one I use and it's great for this purpose. You can load before all scripts or after, up to you and just adjust the code properly. I think you answered your own question though.

Comment: Yes, user scripts are good, but Im planning on distributing this as chrome extension, thats the whole problem.

Comment: That depends then on your ability to hoist the mechanisms or write-over top. Nothing would in theory prevent you from destroying all scripts and reloading your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to intercept every script and manipulate the contents of the script before it is being executed in the browser.

> The short answer is No. You cannot intercept external scripts using Chrome Extension Content Scripts but you can intercept using webRequestAPI in Manifest V2 (Note - It's going away soon)

Your best bet is to write a Proxy application that intercepts the scripts and modifies the contents of the scripts as per the User or your business logic.

We have solved a similar problem at [Requestly](https://requestly.io) by offering a desktop app-based solution So you can launch a browser from the Requestly Desktop App and then create [Modify Response Rule](https://requestly.io/feature/modify-response/) in the Desktop App which allows you to define a static response or change the existing response pragmatically.

### Launching Apps

[image]

### Modifying Response Pragmatically

[image: Change Response Programatically]

Once you do this, your scripts will be intercepted and your code will run on top of the existing responses from the server.

You can build a similar application like this for your case. I am afraid this isn't possible with Chrome Extensions.